Spring project doesn't detect the packages correctly
i'm developing a Spring project as an exercise.
My project correctly connects to the DB, but it doesn't autogenerate the tables. So, for now i had to create them myself. I thought the problem was i got something wrong with my .yml file, but i think i figured it's not the case.
The reason I say this is because i tried to implement a Mapper using the MapStruct dependency, and every time i run the project, no matter what i did, it would give me an error on the @Autowired tag, because he could not find the bean.
The hierarchy where the mapper is located is:
src
  main
     java
        it.prenota.ticket
            model
              entity
              dto
              mapper
                 PazienteMapper.java
            ..
            ..
            TicketApplication.java

So, as you can see, in "it.prenota.ticket" i have the Main class, and all the packages.
The code where i used this mapper is the following:
@Service
public class PazienteService {

    @Autowired
    private PazienteRepository pazienteRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PazienteMapper pazienteMapper;

    public List<PazienteDto> getAll() {
        List<Paziente> pazienteList = pazienteRepository.findByIsActiveTrue();
        return pazienteMapper.toDtos(pazienteList);
    }

This is the error i got:
Field pazienteMapper in it.prenota.ticket.service.PazienteService required a bean of type 'it.prenota.ticket.model.mapper.PazienteMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'it.prenota.ticket.model.mapper.PazienteMapper' in your configuration.


I fixed this by adding a @ComponentScan in my Main class, so i found out that something was not working with the scanning.
But now, even if I "fixed" that problem, by looking online i found out that if Spring doesnt' correctly detect the package with the entities, it would obviously not create the tables in my db.
Now i need help actually fixing this problem. It's so strange because i simply created a project with Spring initializer, the Main class is above all the packages as it should be, since i read that this is the main reason of this kind of problems (in fact i can use my Controller correctly with postman, so my project scans some packages but other... don't?). So maybe i'm missing something.
Here's my .yml file.
spring:
  application:
    name: esercitazione

  jmx:
    default-domain: it.prenota.ticket

  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        default_schema: public
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true

  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tutordb
    username: postgres
    password: indra
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      maximumPoolSize: 5
      minimumIdle: 1


Here's my pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.prenota</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ticket</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

          <!-- Mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


And here's the hierarchy of my packages:

And this is what the console tells me when i run my program:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=62936:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\rarienzo\Desktop\tutoring\ticket\target\classes;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.8\spring-aop-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.22\aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.1.0\HikariCP-5.1.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.8\spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.5.2.Final\hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.1.2\jandex-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.7.0\classmate-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.16\byte-buddy-1.14.16.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.5\jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.5\jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.2\angus-activation-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.5\txw2-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.3.0\spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.3.0\spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.1.8\spring-orm-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.8\spring-context-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.8\spring-tx-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.8\spring-beans-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.1.8\spring-aspects-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-web-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.3.0\spring-boot-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.3.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.5.6\logback-classic-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.5.6\logback-core-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.23.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.23.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.23.1\log4j-api-2.23.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-json-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.17.1\jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.17.1\jackson-annotations-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.17.1\jackson-core-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.17.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.17.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.17.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.8\spring-web-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.13.0\micrometer-observation-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.13.0\micrometer-commons-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.8\spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.8\spring-expression-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.5.3.Final\mapstruct-1.5.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.7.3\postgresql-42.7.3.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.42.0\checker-qual-3.42.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.32\lombok-1.18.32.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.3\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.8\spring-core-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.8\spring-jcl-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui\2.5.0\springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api\2.5.0\springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-starter-common\2.5.0\springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-core-jakarta\2.2.21\swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.21.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.14.0\commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-annotations-jakarta\2.2.21\swagger-annotations-jakarta-2.2.21.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-models-jakarta\2.2.21\swagger-models-jakarta-2.2.21.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.17.1\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\rarienzo\.m2\repository\org\webjars\swagger-ui\5.13.0\swagger-ui-5.13.0.jar it.prenota.ticket.TicketApplication
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-05-29T15:05:29.765+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] it.prenota.ticket.TicketApplication      : Starting TicketApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 17360 (C:\Users\user\Desktop\tutoring\ticket\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\Desktop\tutoring\ticket)
2024-05-29T15:05:29.770+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] it.prenota.ticket.TicketApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-29T15:05:31.080+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-29T15:05:31.156+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 66 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-05-29T15:05:32.079+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-29T15:05:32.093+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-29T15:05:32.093+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-05-29T15:05:32.196+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-29T15:05:32.197+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2353 ms
2024-05-29T15:05:32.474+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-29T15:05:32.949+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2de6f1bc
2024-05-29T15:05:32.951+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-29T15:05:33.051+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-05-29T15:05:33.107+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-05-29T15:05:33.141+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-29T15:05:33.507+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-29T15:05:33.598+02:00  WARN 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-05-29T15:05:34.372+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-29T15:05:34.374+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-29T15:05:34.965+02:00  WARN 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-05-29T15:05:35.824+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-05-29T15:05:35.837+02:00  INFO 17360 --- [esercitazione] [           main] it.prenota.ticket.TicketApplication      : Started TicketApplication in 6.548 seconds (process running for 7.128)


I don't know if it's worth nothing, but i first started using my project with Eclipse, then i switched to IntelliJ.

You might want to share some more details, e.g. where your entities are (I assume in the "model" package), which dependencies you added (i.e. your pom.xml - did you add the spring jpa dependencies?), details on what was wrong with MapStruct as those could provide insights into a bigger problem with your setup, any error messages you get either when trying to use your code or at startup.

In general Spring scans for components in the package the application class is in and all sub packages by default. Anything else would need to be set via @ComponentScan etc. Additionally, you might have to enable JPA first via @EnableJpaRepositories on your application class.

I added more details (yes, the model package contains the dto package, the entity package and the mapper package). I also added the pom file and the error i used to have when using mapstruct. Thing is, i made other Sprign projects in the past, but I never had to use @ComponentScan or things like these. I followed the exact same steps i used to, but this time something's wrong.

Ditch the @ComponentScan that isn't the solution. what is the solution is to correctly setup Lombok to work with MapStruct, setting those up together is quite tricky.

I actually don't need MapStruct anymore, i created the mapper by myself and works like a charm. But i can tell that something else is off, since i had that Autowired problem in the beginning and now it doesn't automatically create the tables (even though i set up hibernate to do so)
